# Parsing with JSON.parse() returns the wrong unexpected token

Tags: json

When writing `JSON.parse("hi")` getting the following error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'h', "hi" is not valid JSON**
When writing `JSON.parse("foo")` getting the following error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "foo" is not valid JSON**
Why is **f** letter ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse("false")` is acceptable, so it's reading the "f" as a potential start of the "false" string, but failing when the next character isn't "a".